# C# - Searching a TextView Multi-line

Tags: c#, android, string, xamarin, textview

I have created a Multi Line TextView in C# using Xamarin but need some help with searching through it using the users input.

This is the multi line textview -

```
           TextView productList1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.productList);
```

The Data -

```
       productList1.Text += "Tomato Soup" + System.Environment.NewLine;
       productList1.Text += "Yo-yo" + System.Environment.NewLine;
       productList1.Text += "Hammer" + System.Environment.NewLine;
```

The statement which doesn't work -

```
if (productSearch.Text.Contains(productList1.ToString()) == true)
            {
               editingResult.Text = "Found";
            }
```

With productSearch being the users input and editingResult being a textview where the "Found" is being shown.

However, I can use this statement to search which works fine but I wish to search through the entire list not individually.

```
    if (productSearch.Text.Contains("Hammer") == true)
           {
               editingResult.Text = "Found";
            }
```

Any Ideas?

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried with `if (productSearch.Text.Contains(productList1.Text.ToString()))` using the `Text` property of your `TextView` and you don't need `== true`

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Or perhaps it should be the other way around: `if (productList1.Text.Contains(productSearch.Text.ToString()))`

Comment: Thank You that works perfectly. It works with or without ToString(). Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
if (productList1.Text.Contains(productSearch.Text.ToString()))
{
     editingResult.Text = "Found";
}
```